# ssmtp не отправляет сообщения Centos 7

Tags: centos, smtp, sendmail

При попытке отправить сообщение появляется ошибка:

```
[root@poyuzd ~]# echo "test_message" | ssmtp -v "example@yandex.ru"
ssmtp: Cannot open smtp.gmail.com:587
```

Конфиг файла ssmpt.conf:

```
TLS_CA_FILE=/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
root=exaple@gmail.com

mailhub=smtp.gmail.com:587

# Where will the mail seem to come from?
rewriteDomain=gmail.com

# The full hostname
hostname=smtp.gmail.com:587
FromLineOverride=YES
UseTLS=YES
AuthMethod=LOGIN
AuthUser=examle@gmail.com
UseSTARTTLS=YES
AuthPass=example
# Are users allowed to set their own From: address?
```

Файл revaliases:

```
examle.com:smtp.gmail.com:587
username:example@gmail.com:smtp.gmail.com:587
```

Логи:

```
tail -f /var/log/maillog
May  5 13:12:01 poyuzd sSMTP[25127]: Unable to locate smtp.gmail.com
May  5 13:12:01 poyuzd sSMTP[25127]: Cannot open smtp.gmail.com:587
May  5 13:12:01 poyuzd sSMTP[25126]: Unable to locate smtp.gmail.com
May  5 13:12:01 poyuzd sSMTP[25126]: Cannot open smtp.gmail.com:587
May  5 13:12:01 poyuzd sSMTP[24863]: Unable to locate smtp.gmail.com
May  5 13:12:01 poyuzd sSMTP[24863]: Cannot open smtp.gmail.com:587
May  5 13:12:01 poyuzd sSMTP[24869]: Unable to locate smtp.gmail.com
May  5 13:12:01 poyuzd sSMTP[24869]: Cannot open smtp.gmail.com:587
May  5 13:12:04 poyuzd sSMTP[25158]: Unable to locate smtp.gmail.com
May  5 13:12:04 poyuzd sSMTP[25158]: Cannot open smtp.gmail.com:587
```

Подскажите пожалуйста в чем может быть ошибка.

Comment: [`hostname=имя.вашего.сервера.каким.его.видно.из.внешнего.мира`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SSMTP#Forward_to_a_Gmail_mail_server)

Comment: @alexanderbarakin имя хоста определяется просто командой 'hostname'?

Comment: вам надо указать то имя, под каким ваш сервер видно из внешнего мира. обычно оно **никак** не пересекается с выдачей программы *hostname* (т.е., содержимым файла `/etc/hostname`)

Comment: @alexanderbarakin А можете пожалуйста подсказать как узнать это имя?

Comment: например, можно обратиться с вопросом к вашему системному администратору

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Спасибо, а самому это никак не узнать?

Comment: судя по вашему непониманию (проявляющемуся в заданных вопросах), внешнее имя у вашего сервера отстутствует. ну, попробуйте указать внешний ip-адрес. надеюсь, хоть эту информацию вы сможете найти с помощью запроса в yandex/google/etc.